# Should one use an apostrophe when referencing a decade?

Tags: punctuation

Should one use an apostrophe when referencing a decade?

For example, consider the following sentence:

> I am looking for an antique pool table from the 1890s.

Should it be as shown above, or rather, as shown below with an apostrophe?

> I am looking for an antique pool table from the 1890's.

Comment: It's a matter of style, so you can do it with an apostrophe, or you can do it the right way.

Comment: @nnnnnn - your comment is a contradiction and wasn't really helpful. You are saying the "right way" is without the apostrophe. You also say it is a matter of style.

Comment: It *is* a matter of style, so pick the way you prefer and do it consistently. My comment about the right way was a formulaic joke indicating my own preference.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of style. You can see from the following [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1890s%2C1890%27s&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), that there has been an increasing tendency since the 1970s to omit the apostrophe.

[image]